# Long running calculation on background thread

Tags: objective-c

In my Cocos2D game for iOS I have a relatively long running calculation that happens at a fairly regular interval (every 1-2 seconds). I'd like to run the calculation on a background thread so the main thread can keep the animation smooth.

The calculation is done on a grid. Average grid size is about 100x100 where each cell stores an integer. Should I copy this grid when I pass it to the background thread? Or can I pass a reference and just make sure I don't write to the grid from the main thread before the background thread is done?

Copying seems a bit wasteful but passing a reference seems risky. So I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee that no writing will be done to the grid during this process that will cause any deadlocks or race conditions or invalidate the calculation, then pass the reference. But I'm guessing you can't guarantee this, so copying the grid is usually worth it.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the response. If I have an `NSArray *myArray` that contains instances of `NSArray` will doing `[myArray copy]` suffice? I'm not sure of the deep vs shallow copy issues.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the copy message doesn't do deep-copying, and that your NSArray will likely only be storing pointers, unaware of the fact that more content needs to be copied. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject) mention this copyWithZone message, which suggests to me that it's not unlike a memcpy, which definitely won't do any deep copying for you.